Show that holomorphic function is polynomial of degree less than n
Let $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow X$ be a holomorphic function such that $|f(z)| = o(|z|^d)$ as $|z| \rightarrow \infty$. Here X is a complex Banach space. How do we go about proving that f is a polynomial of degree less than d? The tricky part here is that the codomain is a Banach space.

what is exactly a polynomial when values are in a Banach space?

a polynomial whose coefficients are in the banach space

I see, so something like $f(z)=z^2w_2+zw_1+w_0$ for some vectors $w_0,w_1,w_2$ - what about if you compose your $f$ with continuous linear maps on $X$ so get entire functions with same rate of growth so usual complex polynomials $a_{\phi,d}z^d+...a_{\phi,0}$ and then show that $a_{\phi,d}=\phi(w_d)$ for a fixed $w_d$ and all $\phi$ and so on

Let $\phi\in X^*$ be an arbitrary functional. Then $f_\phi(z):=\phi(f(z))$ is an entire scalar-valued function with growth $|f_\phi(z)|=o(|z|^d)$, hence it is a polynomial of degree at most $d-1$. Let $a_1^\phi,\dots, a_{d-1}^\phi$ be the coefficients of such polynomial. Basically, we need to find $a_1,\dots, a_{d-1}$  elements of $X$ such that, for any $\phi$ we have
$$\phi(a_i)=a_i^\phi.$$
While a-priori the search could be difficult, we can use Cauchy's formula:
$$a_i:=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta^{i+1}}d\zeta.$$
By commutation properties of the integral we have
$$\phi(a_i)=\phi\left(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta^{i+1}}d\zeta\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\phi(f(\zeta))}{\zeta^{i+1}}d\zeta=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{f_\phi(\zeta)}{\zeta^{i+1}}d\zeta=a_i^{\phi}.
 $$
Define now $g:=\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}a_iz^i$. It follows from the above that for any $\phi$ we have $$\phi(g(z))=\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}a_i^{\phi}z^i=f_\phi(z)=\phi(f(z)).$$
Since $X^*$ separates $X$, $g(z)=f(z)$ and we are done.
Final remark:
The above proof works in more general spaces as well: say $X$ is a quasi-complete locally convex vector space and $f:\mathbb C\to X$ is a weakly-holomorphic function such that for any continuous seminorm $p$, $p(f(z))=o(|z|^d)$. Then $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\le d-1$. The proof is exactly the same (though one needs to argue a little more carefully about the continuity of $f$ and the existence of the dunford-pettis integral, see my answer here)
